# Memory Allocation in iphone

Tags: iphone, memory, allocation

I am checking memory allocation in performance tool, i am getting more than 90 MB memory allocation while running an app for 30-40 mins.Can anyone tell me at which extent memory allocation can go or there is some specification of APPLE  for memory allocation or what is criteria to upload it on an appstore or what .

Please hme next week app is going to upload on an appstore

Manjot Singh

Comment: This is too vague. What app are you making and what are you suspecting? You need to be more specific or else we cannot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty sure that your app has tons of leaks, if you are saying that memory usage grows during time. This could be the reason why appstore can reject your app, so you'd better fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Instruments* to find memory leaks: in Xcode, chose the menu *Run -> Run with Perfomance Tool -> Leaks*. See for example [this article](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/) or [this article](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/) on how to find and fix memory leaks with *Instruments*.